# Вывод отметок времени с заданным шагом между определенными Timestamp'ами

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, unixtimestamp

Есть массив с интервалами времени в виде Timestamp'ов.
Нужно вывести значения из этого промежутка, включая начало и конец, с шагом в 15 минут.

Пример массива:

```
var timeArray = [
    [1442437200, 1442470500],

    [1442473200, 1442479500],

    [1442483100, 1442489400],

    [1442493000, 1442495700],

    [1442499300, 1442505600],

    [1442508300, 1442508300]
]
```

Для промежутка `[[1442473200, 1442479500],  [1442483100, 1442489400]]` должно получиться `[10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30]`.

Я уже посчитала разницу между интервалами в секундах, а как вывести с шагом 15 минут - не могу сообразить. Как это можно сделать?

[Полный пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfvotk38/1/).

```
var data = [
    [1442437200, 1442470500],

    [1442473200, 1442479500],

    [1442483100, 1442489400],

    [1442493000, 1442495700],

    [1442499300, 1442505600],

    [1442508300, 1442508300]
]
var times = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        var item = moment.tz(data[i][j] * 1000, "Europe/Moscow").format(),
            itemTime = item.slice(item.indexOf('T') + 1, item.indexOf('+')),
            timeFormat = itemTime.slice(0, 5).split(':');
        var secondsHours = parseInt(timeFormat[0]) * 60 * 60,
            secondsMinutes = parseInt(timeFormat[1]) * 60,
            seconds = secondsHours + secondsMinutes;
        times.push(seconds)
    }
    var difference = times[1] - times[0];
    console.log('times__________' + times);
    times = [];
    console.log(difference);
}
```

Comment: 1. Заданные интервалы могут пересекаться/накладываться?
2. 15-минутная отметка никак не округляется? Скажем, интервал закончился в 3:14. Отметку 3:15 точно не ставим?

Comment: там всегда интервалы отдаются кратные 15 , пересекаться не могут, всегда идут последовательно

Comment: В последней паре второе время раньше первого.

Comment: пардон, это я опечаталась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз можно полагаться на корректность входных данных, я бы считал длину каждого интервала в 15-минутных отрезках и столько раз прибавлял к дате-времени начала очередного интервала по 15 минут:

```
var data = [
      [1442437200,1442470500],
      [1442473200,1442479500],
      [1442483100,1442489400],
      [1442493000,1442495700],
      [1442499300,1442505600],
      [1442508300,1442437200],
    ]
    ,times = []
    ,pair
    ,i
    ,n15
    ,D = new Date()
    ,H
    ,M
;

for( pair=0; pair < data.length; pair++){
    n15 = (data[pair][1] - data[pair][0]) / 900;
    for( i=0; i<=n15; i++){
        D.setTime( 1000 * (data[pair][0] + i*900));
        H = D.getHours();
        M = D.getMinutes();
        times.push(
            '' 
            +( H<10 ? '0'+H : H)
            +':'
            +( M<10 ? '0'+M : M)
        );
    }
    times.push('-----'); // для красоты. Уберите : )
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = times.join('<br/>');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/kvxwjrtx/)

---

**N.B.** Этот код полагается на временную зону клиента, в котором его запускают. По Москве тест выдает ваш ожидаемый результат теста. В Хабаровске часы будут иными.

Comment: да, спасибо! но именно нужна временная зона Москвы (+3) и если я верно поняла, то тут не учитывается, если дата будет не текущая

Comment: @ennet, про текущее время в коде речи нет. Объект `Date` каждый раз устанавливается на очередное время начала интервала ф-ей `.setTime()`. А чтобы везде **считать время по Москве** вместо `.getHours()` используйте [`.getUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) и прибавляйте к ним 3. И вместо `.getMinutes()` – `.getUTCMinutes()`. Всё просто! : )

Comment: Спасибо, использовала вашу идею. Если кому то понадобиться, расчет только в интервале https://jsfiddle.net/nfvotk38/5/ с momentjs